# Test fails in net6.0 with no info

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-6.0

So i started writing xunit test in net 6.0 with visual studio 2022 community preview.

Everything was working fine on the first PC.

But then when i set the dev environment on another PC (both windows 10) and i try running tests i get this :

```
========== Starting test run ==========
Testhost process exited with error: . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
Testhost process exited with error: . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
========== Test run aborted: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========
```

With no more information. Where can i find those "diagnostic logs" i don't find info about it on the web.

I tried running tests manually in command terminal with "dotnet test" but i get this :

```
  **dotnet test
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  kis-project-information-core -> D:\Users\Thomas MEDARD\Documents\Apollo\Kis\Booth\Libraries\kis-project-information\sources\binaries\net6.0\kis-project-information-core.dll
  kis-project-information-unit-tests -> D:\Users\Thomas MEDARD\Documents\Apollo\Kis\Booth\Libraries\kis-project-information\sources\binaries\net6.0\kis-project-information-unit-tests.dll
Test run for D:\Users\Thomas MEDARD\Documents\Apollo\Kis\Booth\Libraries\kis-project-information\sources\binaries\net6.0\kis-project-information-unit-tests.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Testhost process exited with error: . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Test Run Aborted.**
```

I ran `dotnet test -verbosity:diagnostic --diag:log.txt` to see details and here is what i get

[log.txt](https://pastebin.com/vuHQULtw)

[log.host.21-11-30_10-19-44_26197_5.txt](https://pastebin.com/ECJyrVMt)

So i see my test is detected but something is going wrong when running it

Comment: Does running the project work normally ?*

Comment: It is a library project so there are no main to run. However project builds normally.

Comment: Have you look into [CS8625](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) and [CS8600](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) and the corresponding files and lines mentioned ?

Comment: Have you looked into the diagnostic logs? Try something like `dotnet test -verbosity:diagnostic --diag:log.txt`

Comment: For clarity i think i will remove nullable to avoid those warnings.
@omajid thanks ! I was looking how to get those diagnostics logs the output was talking about. Il will test and edit (or answer) when i can test this.

Comment: @omajid i added result of your command

Comment: Did you read the logs you posted? They complain that a specific library is missing. Either add it or better yet, find out why it's needed in the first place and remove it. `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` was only used in .NET Framework 4.0 projects to allow them to use `async/await`. No .NET project since 4.5 (definitely no .NET Core project) needs it, unless they use a *very* old library that requires it. In which case, the solution is to upgrade that library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried to read them but they are quite hard to understand.
I searched for Bcl in all my project files but i can't find anything about it. I suspect a problem in .Net 6.0 installation so i'm currently reinstalling it

Comment: Look into the log for exceptions. The `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` has nothing to do with the runtime. It's a compatibiity package used only to allow old .NET 4 projects to use `async/await`. Reinstalling the runtime won't change anything. It's the *project* that uses the missing package, either directly or because it uses another library/package that requires `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, i have no clue to what can have a dependency to this but i just reinstalled and it works. Mayber the error you saw was a consequence to something else.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i updated my answer. I found the real problem, now i need to find a correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found what is happening.

After reinstalling i thought everything worked but actually i found the same problem again.

What i realized is that i was in admin mode on my terminal. When i run the same command from non admin terminal, i get the problem explained.

So my problem is accessing to dotnet. I guess it has something to do with having my source code stored in a different drive from dotnet.

It's still weird that i can build without problem but testing need elevated privileges.